# Software to determine if one ring is free over another

Tags: commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, free-modules

Suppose the fates have given me a polynomial ring $C$ in four indeterminates over $\mathbb Z$ and subrings $A < B < C$. Suppose further that the expressions the fates have given me for generators of $A$ and $B$ are not particularly simple, but that I would still like to determine if $B$ is a free $A$-module. It is now 2022; **is there a way of asking a computer to do this for me?**

**Edit**: It looks like someone is having a bad day, judging by the abuse and the downvote. Allow me to elaborate. I am an occasional user of algebra but not particularly strong in computations. Consider the subgroup $\mathrm{PSp}(4) = \mathrm{Sp}(4)/\mathrm{center}$ of the simply-connected compact exceptional group $E_6$ which is the fixed point set of a certain well known outer automorphism, giving rise to the compact symmetric space of type EI. The inclusion induces an injective map of complex representation rings, and regarding $\mathbb Z$ as a module over $R(E_6)$ by the augmentation, it is known that

$$R(\mathrm{PSp}(4)) \otimes_{R(E_6)} \mathbb Z$$

is a free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank three. The ring $R(\mathrm{PSp}(4))$ injects into the representation ring of a subgroup $\mathrm{SU}(2)\mathrm{Sp}(3)$, so the image of $R(E_6)$ in $R(\mathrm{PSp}(4))$ can be understood in terms of the images of both in $R(\mathrm{SU}(2)\mathrm{Sp}(3))$. This in turn naturally embeds as a subring of $R(\mathrm{SU}(2) \times \mathrm{Sp}(3))$, which is actually a polynomial ring. I would like to use these observations to determine if $R(\mathrm{PSp}(4))$ is free as a module over $R(F_4)$. Unfortunately, the most tractable expressions I have for the images in $R(\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{Sp}(3))$ are not particularly usable, at least so far, and at least for me.

But it has occurred to me that I've used Macaulay to determine if certain sequences are regular, GAP and Sage to count cosets of certain groups, etc., and that a computer may be faster at this sort of thing than me—that in fact this may be a solved problem in the world of computer algebra, and I may just not know the way. If it were, that would be good to know. If not, that would also be interesting. So, **are such problems solvable algorithmically, and if so, does a currently existing package do it?**

Comment: Wow, how pointlessly unpleasant.

Comment: I don't understand your grievance, but I hope you don't treat people you meet in real life like this.

Comment: And you've deleted your comments to go with the downvote. Inspiring, @markvs.

Comment: The answer is, of course, yes. See the well named Macaulay2 function "[isFreeModule](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.18/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_is__Free__Module.html)". I'm not sure if there's more to your question than this, since it's easy to find by googling.

Comment: Thank you! My memory of Macaulay2 from years ago was that I had had difficulty defining subrings in terms of generators and considering rings as modules over subrings, and had wound up using a number of partial workarounds with the isRegularSequence and basis commands. I've since found it is much easier to define subrings than I had remembered; I don't know if the functionality changed or I just searched poorly back then. So I guess the "more" now is when I am asking if $B$ is a free module, how to specify I am considering it as a module over $A$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I'm not so sure that function is really well named: it doesn't check if a module is isomorphic to some free module; module are given by a list of generators living in some ambient free module, and this function checks if the submodule is equal to its ambient free module. The function prune (well named?) computes a presentation.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena -- Sure, but the linked documentation clarifies that exact source of confusion. Of course, it's always nice to clarify these things ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor — I've appreciated both your contributions, but I'm still trying, believe it or not, to get at a more elementary issue, that of whether it is possible/easy to get Macaulay to return this information for B as a module over a subring A, rather than ZZ or QQ. Any insight on this matter you might have, however obvious, would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm actually planning to leave an answer once I have time to get a minimal example working, which should hopefully be later tonight/tomorrow. I'm just a bit busy with my own stuff right now and haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... annoyingly it looks like Macaulay2 only lets you do this when $B$ is module-finite over $A$.

The relevant function is `pushForward` (documentation [here](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.17/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_push__Forward_lp__Ring__Map_cm__Module_rp.html)) which takes a $B$-module $M$ and a ring map $f : A \to B$ and returns the [pushforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923785/definition-of-pushforward-and-pullback-for-modules) $f^* M$, which is an $A$-module. There's another function `pushFwd` (documentation [here](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.18/share/doc/Macaulay2/PushForward/html/_push__Fwd_lp__Ring__Map_cm__Module_rp.html)) provided you `loadPackage "PushForward"` first.

Both `pushForward` and `pushFwd` throw an error if $f^* M$ is not a finitely generated $A$-module, so for your purposes, an error will be thrown if $B$ is not module-finite over $A$. I've looked around for a while (which was the source of the long delay before posting this answer) and I wasn't able to find a way around this (at least not with Macaulay2). Hopefully somebody who knows better than me comes around, and either shows a function that I missed, or maybe a way to do this with [singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) (which I didn't look into, because I'm not familiar with it). It seems reasonable that the finitely-generated assumption can't be lifted, because I'm not sure how a computer would be able to do computations on an infinitely generated module.

Anyways, here's a minimal working example (in Macaulay2) in case $B$ is module-finite over $A$:

```
A = QQ[t]
B = QQ[x,y] / (x*y, y^2)
C = QQ[a,b] / (b^2)

f = map(B,A,{x}) -- the map sending t |--> x
g = map(C,A,{a}) -- the map sending t |--> a

M = B^1 -- B as a B-module in the obvious way
N = C^1

-- now we can view M and N as A-modules
-- (throws an error if we get something that isn't module finite over A)
M' = pushForward (f, M)
N' = pushForward (g, N)

-- now we prune to get a minimal presentation
M' = prune M'
N' = prune N'

-- and lastly we check if the presentation is free
isFreeModule M' -- returns false
isFreeModule N' -- returns true
```

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This helps a good deal. My rings are algebras over `ZZ` rather than `QQ`, and I got errors until I transitioned to `QQ`. I do get the expected answer after extending coefficients, that the one is free of rank three over the other. Perhaps I could examine the generators manually over `ZZ` if I knew them, though. Is there a standard way to make it tell you? `prune` and `minimalPresentation` just tell me it is free of rank 3, and `basis` tells me it is not finite over the base, presumably because the base it is thinking of is `QQ` and not A-tensor-`QQ`.

Comment: Typically you can use `gens M` in order to get the generators of a module `M`. Usually `M` is presented as the cokernel of a map, and you need to do a bit of work by hand to get that in a slightly more human-readable form. You can also use `res M` to compute a free resolution. Then `(res M).dd` will display the resolution plus matrices giving the maps in the resolution. You should be able to use these to get what you're after ^_^

Comment: Thank you! For generators, it gives a 3x3 identity matrix, for free resolution, it gives itself in degree 0 and the zero module in degree 1, and the `.dd` variant is a more verbose version of that. I think that what's happened is that it has identified this with the standard free module of rank 3 over A-tensor-`QQ` so that the generators don't exist as elements of B-tensor-`QQ` anymore, but are exactly the coordinate basis for the standard free module. I will continue to think about how to make it think of M' in terms of B.